# How do i install crosswalk for android on windows

Tags: android, cordova, ide, crosswalk-runtime

[crosswalk host setup link](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/getting_started/host_setup)

crosswalk is the new way to make html/js based android apps that give somewhat good performance, at least that is what I have heard. To try it out I have to install it. But due it being so unknown, NO tag here for it, there are no `indepth` guides of what to do and especially what to do if something goes wrong. And there are tons of little steps needed, so workflow isn't optimized either. Since all technical sites say ask question here if have any problems I am going to.

Whenever I install crosswalk start step "INSTALLING THE DEVELOPMENT TOOLS"...

I do this:

1. Install utilities (Check Have Git bash)
2. Install python (Already have it)
3. Install Java Dev Kit (Done)
4. Install Ant (never ending command line with beeping??)

So you can see I am stuck here...Ant step. The cli opens with tons encrypted text after this command:

```
curl http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.zip \-o ant.zip
```

The thing just keeps going on... So what should I do? is it how it's supposed to be?

Thanks in advance for any assistance. Or if you think I should just leave crosswalk forever or for now than let me know why you think that.

Comment: oh also it just stops responding if i click it.

Comment: Ok this may sound stupid, I just put the url in browser and it download like in 5 seconds and then took it in C:\user\usernamefolder.. and then just unzip it. :D

Comment: http://www.rapidee.com/ for setting up variables easily especially if you happen to install all stuff in their default directories. Like java

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to NOT use git Bash or command line to download. Instead just take the link and download it which will take few second without making anything unresponsive. Compared to cli way where it'd just keep beeping. Once it's downloaded. Just move it to your user folder and extract it either with whatever program you have like winrar or cli.